# Validating input using Angularjs on IE8

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, internet-explorer-8

I have a form (made using divs) that gets displayed when i select an option using dropdown menu.
Am using ng-options for dropdown selections. My issue is I need to support IE8. I know IE8 does not support HTML5, and I can not use the `'required' tag`. Thus, I am trying to use the `"ng-required"` option for form validation but it does not seem to work. I have looked at the jquery validator but I have many forms and each have different criteria. For example, I have a form which requires State/Country in input box which is required for a particular option. However, the same field is optional with the other option. To me, writing a validation for each is not the right approach since am trying to leverage angularjs. 
Please help. 
For example, one of the field is:

```
<div style="float:left; width:290px;margin-bottom: 8px;">
  <div style="float:left; margin-right:8px; width: 113px; text-align: right;"> (*)Document Number: </div>
  <div style="float:left; margin-right:8px;width: 160px;">
  <input type="text" ng-model="customerData.docNmbr" placeholder=" Document Number" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-required> </div>
</div>
```

and my submit button is:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
```

Comment: Please define "does not seem to work" and show what you have tried so far...

Comment: What i meant is that "ng-required" does not work on IE8. the validation works fine on chrome/firefox. I have made submit button disabled till the form is valid but that does not work on IE8. It still submits.

Comment: I have to support IE8 at work, and I just went ahead and used `require` out of the box and it works just fine. Out of curiosity how are you testing it in IE8? If you're running your app **locally** IE8 renders with IE7 standards by default.

Comment: @Matt You are using the 'require' tag? HTML5 has 'required' tag, right? are you using 'ng-required'? Yes am testing it locally on my machine. I can not push it to dev server till this gets resolved. Also, could you provide an example of how you using that?

Comment: Sorry, typo - yeah `required`. To render your app in IE8 standards you can set this via the F12 developer tools; or set it with a meta content tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`.

Comment: @Matt Thanks a lot Matt. I will try this out. You might want to add that to the answer. I cant voteup (because i dont have the reputation points but am sure others will).

Comment: That's fine PJ - I'm interested to see if it works so be sure to comment if it does. If it doesn't it may be a case that one of the libraries i'm using is implementing it for me.

Comment: @Matt It did help i guess. The fields do highlight now if it is not filled. I will test the form submission as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is to use another library like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/). The main objective of this library is to standardize somehow old browser like IE8 with some of the new HTML5 Features. If you want to learn more about it this is a good article:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using-modernizr.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dalorzo. Alas, I can not use modernizr since the libraries/plugins i can use have already been restricted by the team. :( I tried to work around something similar to this '
    <!--[if lte IE 8] >
    <script>
        document.createElement('ng-include');
        document.createElement('ng-required'); ' but it does not work either.

Comment: I can't fly because I am limited by gravity but if I have an issue and this has been solved by other team how I can put limits to that, just my thought :D

Comment: :D I understand what you mean, but am helpless in this regard.

Comment: I would vote-up for your suggestion but i can not because i dont have the reputation points. It needs 15!

Comment: Modernizr doesn't actually polyfill HTML5 features into older browsers. It only provides feature detection, which you can use to determine whether or not polyfills are needed or to supply alternative script.